# How to change handling of internal server error?

Tags: java, web-applications, error-handling, oas

My application produces an internal server error, running on tomcat it prints a stacktrace with the given error. On Oracle it hides the error and post it to `application.log`.

Is it possible to change this setting via the deployment descriptor?

```
500 Internal Server Error

Servlet error: An exception occurred. The current application deployment
descriptors do not allow for including it in this response. 

Please consult the application log for details.
```

Comment: Which web server and/or web container (or application server) are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define error handling pages in your web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/pages/500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

If the error code is explicitly set by your application make sure it uses [response.sendError()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int%29) and not [response.setStatus()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus%28int%29) because the latter will ignore your custom error pages defined in web.xml

p.s By googling your error message I assume that this is a Java web application running on [OAS](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/application-server/index.htm)